# Accurev CLI - Quick way to find if already logged in

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

In Accurev, what is the quick command I can use to find out whether a login session is active now?

I am building an application where I used `accurev login <username> <password>` command to login to accurev.

After some time, I wanted to verify if the session is still available. Based on that, I will either re login or just use the previous session.

I can use `accurev info` to see the principal, but I feel that is also taking some time to return the results. Is there any other better way?

Note that I don't want to persist the login session using `-n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specific command to get your authorization level within AccuRev. You can use "accurev secinfo" and you can expect to see three different outputs:

- authuser: you are logged in with a username that has a non-empty password.
- anyuser: you are logged in with a username that has an empty password.
- notauth: you are not logged in.

The output will be a single word. For users that login within a password, you can expect to see either "authuser" or "notauth". For a user that does not have a password set, you will see either "anyuser" or "notauth". The output "notauth" in both instances will tell you the session has expired.

Comment: i will wait for some more days, and then accept this as answer, if no one responds better than this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two strategies for dealing with session timeouts for AccuRev commands.  The first strategy (which is the one in your question) is to test for whether you are logged in.  For this, "accurev info" is as good as any other command.  There won't be any AccuRev commands faster than this one.

An alternative strategy without the extra command overhead that you can use is to wrap the execution of AccuRev commands with code that will re-login and retry the command if the command fails with a "session expired".  The exit code of 52 is uniquely returned from AccuRev commands to indicate not logged in or expired session.  As a windows example:

```
C:\Users\me>accurev show streams
Not authenticated (no session). Please use the 'login' command to authenticate.

C:\Users\me>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
52
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this command:

accurev show sessions